# Improper integrals: does convergence imply monotonicity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, improper-integrals

If the integral from $1$ to $\infty$ for a positive, continuous function (on $[1, \infty)$) converges, does this imply the function is decreasing as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can even have $f$ unbounded. For instance, define $f$ to be, on the interval $[k, k+1]$, a triangle of the height $k$ and base $2/k^3$. Then $$\int_1^\infty f(t) \, dt=\sum_k \frac 1{k^2} <\infty,$$ and $f$ is unbounded on any interval $[m, \infty]) $.

If you center the triangles on each $k$, you can get $f(k) =k$.

If you want $f(t)>0$ for all $t$, you can raise each triangle by $1/k^2$ and join the endpoint of one triangle with the starting point of the next one by a line segment.

Comment: if the integral conveges,f is pos and cts, then is the series convergent?

Comment: No. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, the function does not have to be monotonous, example:

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin^2{x}+1}{x^2}$$

Comment: what can we say about the series from 1 to infinity of f? does it converge?

Comment: @Zexion12 you mean - if it does converge whether it's monotonous?

Comment: no, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ coverge under the same assumptions without knowing if $f$ decreases?

Comment: What is $n$ and what is $dx$ since you're not integrating? This does not make sense

Comment: sorry I fixed it... long night

Comment: @Zexion12 what are the assumptions? in your question it was convergence, here you're asking about convergence

Comment: if the integral conveges,f is pos and cts, then is the series convergent?

Comment: Ah, no. You can define a function like above for all numbers but integers and $f(x) = 1$ for integers, then the integral converges and the series doesn't

Comment: but then the function is not cts.

Comment: @Zexion12 you're right, I didn't notice that, then I'd say yes, but I do not have the reference for that

Comment: -1: this answer is wrong, it is is not necessarily true that $f$ converges to zero.

Comment: @MartinArgerami you're right, thank you! I have removed the wrong part, still the counterexample holds

Comment: Note that your $f$ is not positive.

Comment: @MartinArgerami you're right and if I think about it, triangle is not as well;>

Comment: Yes, but it's non-negative and one can simply lift the "zero" part by $1/k^2$ on each interval to make it strictly positive. You example takes negative values.